# Is there a way to detect if a user is watching a video with an extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I'm trying to make an extension (firefox & Chrome) where the goal is to identify whether the user is actively engaged or inactive. Activities such as web surfing, watching videos, and listening to music should be considered as active interactions. To detect web surfing, I plan to monitor mouse and keyboard input. However, I'm not sure if it is possible to detect if a user is watching a video. My original idea was to detect if audio is playing in a tab, but couldn't find any info on that.

Comment: There are Chrome extensions like https://www.mutetab.com or [Go To Playing Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/go-to-playing-tab/hmbhamadknmmkapmhbldodoajkcggcml), I suppose if you check their code you could get an idea how they are doing it.

Comment: Use `document.querySelector(':playing')` in your content script.